# how to change values in an list and create a new list

Tags: python, arrays, list, if-statement, for-loop

Code:

```
a = [4,4,6,4,10]

for i in a:
    if i == 4:
        i = i + 10
        print(i)
```

I want this code to form a new array, which is:

```
b = [14,14,6,14,10]
```

I don't understand how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break it down in to parts. Right now you are actually properly checking for a number that equals to 4 and incrementing it by 10, which is great.

You are right now missing two key components:

1. Creating a new list and appending to it
2. An `else` condition for all the other elements that you want.

So, for the first part, start by creating a new list:

```
new_list = []
```

So, we have:

```
a = [4,4,6,4,10]
new_list = []
```

Then, you want to `append` to your new list:

```
for i in a:
    if i == 4:
        i = i + 10
        new_list.append(i)
```

However, now, you need to accommodate for the values you do not want to increment, this is where you need an `else` condition:

So, if it does not equal to `4`, simply append the value as is to your new list:

```
for i in a:
    if i == 4:
        i = i + 10
        new_list.append(i)
    else:
        new_list.append(i)
```

That pretty much corrects the problems you had in your code.

Now, one small adjustment to make, is that this line:

```
i = i + 10
```

Can be re-written as: `i += 10`

So, finally, we have:

```
a = [4,4,6,4,10]
new_list = []

for i in a:
    if i == 4:
        i += 10
        new_list.append(i)
    else:
        new_list.append(i)
```

Finally, this can all be shortened in to one line as:

```
new_list = [i + 10 if i == 4 else i for i in a]
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be easily done with a list comprehension:

```
>>> a = [4,4,6,4,10]
>>> b = [14 if x == 4 else x for x in a]
>>> b
[14, 14, 6, 14, 10]
```

or alternatively, closer to your original code:

```
[i + 10 if i == 4 else i for i in a]
```

The problem with your code is that the line

```
i = i + 10
```

does not modify the values of the list. All you do is **rebind** the name `i` to `i + 10` - but then you do nothing with the new value.

The traditional way, without a list comprehension, would look like this:

```
>>> a = [4,4,6,4,10]
>>> b = [] # empty result list
>>> for item in a:
...     if item == 4:
...         b.append(14) # alternatively: b.append(item + 10)             
...     else:
...         b.append(item)
... 
>>> b
[14, 14, 6, 14, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for idx in range(len(a)):
    i = a[idx]
    if i == 4:
        i = i+10
        a[idx] = i
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!